# RegEx for splitting text with abbreviations into sentences

Tags: javascript, regex, text, split

I have a text. I need get a list of sentences. There are a lot of subtleties, such as dot being used in abbreviations.
I found this Regex

`(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s`

But it's not working correctly

For example I have this text:

> The house No. 19 was very old. People said that there lived ghosts but
>   nobody had ever seen them. However, it wasn’t called a «haunted»
>   house; year after year it remained: "To Be Let or Sold"
>
> The house agent Mr. Raddish was glad to see that Mrs. Lancaster was
>   interested in this house. But her question: «How long was it empty?»
>   made him a little worried: «Er — er — some time,» he answered.

That's how it splited using this regex

*The house No. 19 was very old.

People said that there lived ghosts but nobody had ever seen them.

However, it wasn’t called a «haunted» house; year after year it remained: "To Be Let or Sold"*

*The house agent Mr. Raddish was glad to see that Mrs.

Lancaster was interested in this house.

But her question: «How long was it empty?» made him a little worried: «Er — er — some time,» he answered.*

As u can see it split sentence with Mrs. But i don't wanna this

It should look like this:

*The house No. 19 was very old.

People said that there lived ghosts but nobody had ever seen them.

However, it wasn’t called a «haunted» house; year after year it remained: "To Be Let or Sold"*

*The house agent Mr. Raddish was glad to see that Mrs. Lancaster was interested in this house.

But her question: «How long was it empty?» made him a little worried: «Er — er — some time,» he answered.*

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: So you are going to build a list of every thing that ends with a dot that is not the end of a sentence? Also weird that Mr. would have a dot....

Comment: I wanna get a list all sentences on page to add ability to translate whole sentence on click. But i have problems if sentence contains abbreviations

Comment: There is no reg exp that can determine if it is an abv or not. So your need to either have a list of all possible abbreviations.

Comment: What if the last word of a sentence is an abbreviation? This is an unexpectedly tricky problem.

Comment: @epascarello are you missing an "or" to go with "either"?

Comment: [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/choose-whole-sentences-and-only-whole-sentences-reliably-with-regex/8075) is a blog post discussing a much more complex regexp that tries to do it.

Comment: NLP(Natural language processing) would be more adapted than regex to solve this kind of task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers guys.
NLP is a fantastic solution.
[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/q12b74jn/1/) is a correct solution:

```js
const txt = `The house No. 19 was very old. People said that there lived ghosts but nobody had ever seen them. However, it wasn’t called a «haunted» house; year after year it remained: "To Be Let or Sold"

The house agent Mr. Raddish was glad to see that Mrs. Lancaster was interested in this house. But her question: «How long was it empty?» made him a little worried: «Er — er — some time,» he answered.`;
let sentences = nlp(txt).sentences().data()
for (var s of sentences) {
  document.body.innerHTML += s.text + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/compromise@latest/builds/compromise.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could do to help do it with RegEx , as RegEx is going to be faster than a full NLP analysis, that if you require performance.

```
.+?(?:(?<![\s.]\p{Lu}|r|rof|s|rs|iss|o)[.!?]|$)
```